# Rtweet search multiple accounts

Tags: rtweet

I have a project which I need to get tweets from companies twitter accounts. I plan to use the  rtweet package in R and run the search_fullarchive. My question is how can I link a list of accounts to the q? I'm trying just with 2 accounts names in the search_tweets fucntion, but it is not returning any observations. However, when I just use 1 name account it works.

> queryaccounts <- "from:Amazon AND Microsoft"

> ts11<- search_tweets(q = queryaccounts,n = 10,type = "recent")

Does anyone Know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
queryaccounts <- c("from:Amazon", "from:Microsoft")
ts11<- search_tweets(q = queryaccounts,n = 10,type = "recent")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).